# Wordpress: hide "Number of items per page" option for no Admin users

Tags: wordpress, hook

I need to  hide "Number of items per page" option for no Admin users.
Take a look to this capture to see what I mean:
[image]

I've got this code which does the job but the problem is that the code remove All Screen Options (Columns and Pagination). I only need to remove the Pagination area: "Number of items per page"

How can I do this?

```
add_action('admin_init', 'hide_number_items_no_admin');
function hide_number_items_no_admin() {
    if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        // hide screen options for everyone but the admin
        add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options_tab');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options in the "Screen Options" panel are rendered based on an `_options` property on the screen object, one of which is `per_page`.

You can use the `in_admin_header` hook to modify the current screen a little after the `per_page` option is added:

```
add_action( 'in_admin_header', 'hide_number_items_no_admin' );
function hide_number_items_no_admin(){
    if( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        return;
    }

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if( !$screen ){
        return;
    }

    $screen->add_option( 'per_page', null );
};
```

Comment: Working fine for me